# SAS: Mean, median, max and percentiles by two variables

Tags: sas, proc

I have a dataset structured with 5 columns.
Month, User, Num1, Num2, Num3.

I'm trying to calculate, for each Num1 Num2 and Num3, the mean, median, max, 25th and 75th percentile for each permutation of Month and User.

I have tried proc univariate but I can't do it without creating a macro and manual steps for each Month and User permutation.

My ideal output would then look like this, and separate outputs for Num1 Num2 Num3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjcrg.png

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and provide sample input data, and what the desired output should look like.

Answer (score 1):

PROC Means does what you want.

Here is an example with the SASHELP.SHOES example dataset.

```
ods html;
proc means data=sashelp.shoes mean median max p25 p75;
   class region product;
   var sales inventory returns;
run;
ods html close;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the PROC MEANS ?

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm

Or can you give a sample input data so I can try to recreate the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sort data = mydata;
 by month user;
run;

proc univariate data = mydata;
 by month user;
 var num1 num2 num3;
run;
```

You can probably refine this to get only the exact statistics you want using either ODS SELECT or OUTPUT