# How to calculate mean across two variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a data set which contains data on the average price of unleaded regular gasoline (per gallon), whole large eggs (per dozen), and whole milk (per gallon). The variables in this file are year, month, price, and type of commodity.

```
Year Month  Price   Commodity
2004    1   1.592   Gas
2004    2   1.672   Gas
2005    1   1.766   Gas
2005    2   1.833   Gas
2006    1   2.009   Gas
2006    2   2.041   Gas
2004    1   1.95    Egg
2004    2   1.979   Egg
2005    1   1.97    Egg
2005    2   1.951   Egg
2006    1   2.032   Egg
2006    2   2.21    Egg
2004    1   2.879   Milk
2004    2   2.814   Milk
2005    1   2.786   Milk
2005    2   2.906   Milk
2006    1   3.374   Milk
2006    2   3.574   Milk
```

Can anyone help me to create a data set that contains the average price per year for each commodity?

I am able to create a data set that contains the average price per year or per commodity, but unable to calculate average price per year for each commodity.

Note: I am using SAS 9.4 version

Comment: share the desired output. Also, attach whatever you have tried.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thanks for reaching out !

Comment: Great! Show us the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS: Mean, median, max and percentiles by two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707707/sas-mean-median-max-and-percentiles-by-two-variables)

Comment: @Richard 'PROC sort data = price;
by year commodity;
RUN;
PROC sql;
create table avg as
select year, commodity, AVG(price) as avgprice
from price
group by year, commodity;
RUN;
Proc sort data=avg;
by commodity;
Run;'

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this is a simple code that does what you requested:

> ```
> proc sql;
>   select mean(price) as average, year, commodity
>   from have
>   group by commodity, year
>   order by commodity, year;
> quit;
> ```

This gives the output:

> ```
>  average year commodity 
>  1.9645  2004   Egg 
>  1.9605  2005   Egg 
>  2.121   2006   Egg 
>  1.632   2004   Gas 
>  1.7995  2005   Gas 
>  2.025   2006   Gas 
>  2.8465  2004   Milk 
>  2.846   2005   Milk 
>  3.474   2006   Milk
> ```